# Change route outside Ember app

Tags: ember.js, routes, location, history

I'm having a problem with changing route outside Ember app. Code of the app is external and it's not possible to extend it in any ways. What I tried so far:

1. Changing `location.href` (Ember unable to catch this event and full page reload occurs)
2. Using `History.pushState()` (doesn't change anything)
3. Changing `href` attribute on existed link (Ember remembers initial value and ignores new one)
4. Thinking about compiling template with `{{link-to}}` helper, but `Ember.View` isn't globally available. And I don't know routes, however it's not a problem – I need it on one particular service and routes can be reverse engineered.

Maybe there is more elegant way to do it?

Comment: To confirm, you're wanting to make Ember change its route from outside of Ember? If so, I'll write up an answer tomorrow

Comment: @acorncom Yes, exactly. I need it even for specific site – [LinkedIn](https://www.linkedin.com). For example when I'm on [/in/reepush](https://www.linkedin.com/in/reepush) url and then I need to change it to [/in/yehudakatz](https://www.linkedin.com/in/yehudakatz). I looked into sources to understand how templating works, found `Ember.HTMLBars.template` which used for user links, but can't get how I can wire it with internal app state.

Comment: On other point of clarification, since you mention LinkedIn. Are actually working with the source code for the app or are you wanting to control the LinkedIn Ember app from code you write without changing the LinkedIn Ember app? Because those are very different things ;-)

Comment: @acorncom I don't have access to LinkedIn sources. In other case it wouldn't be such a problem :)